# Managing Distribution Groups from Outlook

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, contacts, exchange-2010

I need to be able to have a domain user edit/add/remove contacts from a distribution group. This distribution group will contain contacts (first name, last name, email address) that are external to our domain (gmail, hotmail, etc). Ideally I would like the user to have the ability to do all of this from either Outlook or Outlook Web App using Exchange Control Panel. This user is a normal domain user and I can give whatever permissions are required for them to do this.

I do not want these individual contacts to be listed in the GAL or address book but I want the distribution groups to be available in the address book. Everyone else in the domain will need to be able to email this distribution group.

I have tried creating a distribution group in Exchange and creating contacts in Active Directory and assigning them to the group. However when I create contacts using the Exchange Control Panel, they are being created in the Users OU in Active Directory and they are showing up in the GAL. I'd prefer if the user didn't have to use remote desktop to go on the Exchange/AD servers to set these up.

Is there a way to manage (create/edit/delete) members of distribution group using Outlook or Outlook Web App/Exchange Control Panel without the created contacts showing up in the GAL and being placed in the Users OU in Active Directory?

What other solutions achieve the same results?

We are using Microsoft Office 2010, Microsoft Exchange 2010, Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just manage the group as an Outlook distribution group stored in some shared contacts folder?

Comment: I need an email address for the distribution group (ex: home.staff@domain.tld - for staff home/personal email accounts) Sharing a contact group will pull in all the contacts individually in the TO/CC/BCC fields instead of just 1 address. Sharing the contact group will also create a barrier when other users want to email that group as they will have to be setup with the shared contacts.

Comment: Hrm, this is one of those cases where I find it easier to just move the list over to a list server like mailman or something.

Answer (score 0):

Please deleguate AD right on the OU where you store contact (you can change from the default user's OU), deleguate the Exchange Recipient Administrators right on Exchange to manage those contact and then install the Exchange's  console into the user computer.

The fact you deleguate right in the correct OU make sure the user can only manage contact, as she will need to create them in that OU. (even with the Exchange right, the user can only change user she got access too in the AD)

I dont answer from outlook on the other side, as she can't as it's stored in your AD. (so you have to deleguate all the right I told) As when you create a contact, you need to select an OU for it, outlook can't be used that way.